# Не могу установить phpmyadmin (Elementary OS)

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, elementary-os

Выполняю команду

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

выбивает такое окно

```
│ The phpmyadmin package must have a database installed and      
│ configured before it can be used.  This can be optionally      
│ handled with dbconfig-common.                                  
│                                                                
│ If you are an advanced database administrator and know         
│ that you want to perform this configuration manually, or       
│ if your database has already been installed and                
│ configured, you should refuse this option. Details on what needs to be
│ done should most likely be provided in  
│ /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin.                                     
│                                                                
│ Otherwise, you should probably choose this option.
```

Есть кнопка ОК, но я не могу её нажать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть кнопка ОК, но я не могу его нажать

переходить от поля к полю можно кнопкой <kbd>tab</kbd>.

когда «ok» получит фокус, нажмите <kbd>enter</kbd>.

---

а суть сообщения в том, что для работы программ, входящих в пакет *phpmyadmin* необходима установленная и сконфигурированная база данных.

Comment: но я уже установил mysql, можно как-то проверить установил я её или нет ?

Comment: при установке настройка была? (диалоги для задания пароля пользователя базы данных *root*)

Comment: проверить, установлен ли пакет, можно, например, так: `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server`. узнать статус (работает или нет): `sudo service mysql status`.

Comment: ставил пароль такой командой mysqladmin -u root -p password...нажал я ОК, все дальше пошло но так,  и не запускается phpmyadmin

Comment: задал команды `sg_ua@maxim-Aspire-5733Z:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server
mysql-server     install
mysql-server-5.5    install
mysql-server-core-5.5    install
sg_ua@maxim-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 1362
sg_ua@maxim-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo service mysql status`

Comment: *не запускается phpmyadmin* — задайте новый вопрос по этому поводу, в котором опишите, каким образом вы его пытаетесь запустить.

Comment: *задал команды* — всё в порядке, mysql-server установлен и работает.